# Image uploaded to firebase storage but not visible in app UI

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

When a particular image is selected from ImagePicker it gets uploaded to Firebase Storage successfully but not visible in UI.

MessageAdapter.java:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendlyMessage> {
public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendlyMessage> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

    FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);

    assert message != null;
    boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
    if (isPhoto) {
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(photoImageView);
    } else {
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
    }
    authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Anyone on how to fix this?

Comment: I think the first thing to do is to confirm that the image uploaded was successful. Check firebase storage to confirm that.

    Then confirm if the generated URL after a successful image upload is saved on the message object. 

    If the above are true, then try printing it to the console then confirm the getPhotoUrl() is not null. 

    If it is not empty, then  make sure your upload process has a token generated and attached to the photo url  (&token=a986e967-8e65-487d-a7ef-8476dbf7a11d) so it can be access publicly.

    It will also be helpful to share you upload photo code.

Comment: `load(message.getPhotoUrl())`. How should we know what kind of url you have?

Comment: Further you did not tell if the if block or else block is executed. How can we know?

Comment: What does `message.getPhotoUrl()` return?

Comment: message.getPhotoUrl() returns 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@945da74' Also image is uploaded to firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing my previous code with this one:

```
//upload file to firebase storage
        photoRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null,mUsername,uri.toString());
                        mMsgDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This code returns Uri: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app_name.appspot.com/o/chat_photo%2Fimage%3A61310?alt=media&token=f2a9d6f6-aa4c-4fa9-a66a-6727dd2d0e8d" which is passed to FriendlyMessage object to display an image in the UI.

My Previous code:

```
photoRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> u = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null,mUsername,u.toString());
                        mMsgDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
```

u.toString() was returning this URL: "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@945da74" because getDownloadUrl() was called by using a Reference of TaskSnapshot. This was the reason behind the photo not visible in the UI.